# How to use POST in ajax

Tags: html, jquery, json, ajax

I created a page where after loading the data will appear. I am using github url and ajax POST. But the data is not showing. What should I fix from the code that I have made?

```
<div id="content"> 
</div>
```

```
window.onload = function(){
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/bimobaskoro/hewan/main/kucing.json',
        dataType: 'application/json',
        sucess: function (data) {
            html = '<div class="content" id="content"></div>'
            html += '<h1>' + data.judul + '</h1>'
            html += '<p>' + data.isi + '</p>'
            html += '</div>'
            document.getElementById('content').innerHTML += html;
        },
        error: function() {

        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Do you see any errors in the Console? Do you get any data back when you review Network tab? Your "success" function needs to be spelled correctly.

Comment: success spell is wrong

Comment: You can't POST to a static JSON file hosted by GitHub. You need a server-side process to handle POST requests. GitHub pages does not support such a thing. Why are you trying to POST anyway, you're not sending any data?

Comment: @Phil I believe you can POST to static content, just the command will be treated the same as GET request with no variables. To your point, a static JSON file will not be able to process the POST command and will just respond with JSON data.

Comment: @Twisty nope, the Github servers respond with a 403: _The request made was to forbidden content._ I suspect you could attempt to provide an authorization header but it would probably respond with a 405 then

Comment: @Phil good to know. I suspect with more attack vectors, more web servers disable verbs when not needed or expected for specific file types.

Answer (score 1):

Why would you use post to a json file. Get method is enough.

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/bimobaskoro/hewan/main/kucing.json',
    success: function (data)
    { 
        var html = '<div class="content" id="content">';
        var obj=JSON.parse(data);
        obj.forEach((e)=>{
            html += '<h1>' + e.judul + '</h1>'
            html += '<p>' + e.isi + '</p>'
        });
        
        html += '</div>'
        document.getElementById('content').innerHTML = html;    
    }
});
```

Comment: Thank your for the answer, but I want the data to appear on the page not in the console

Answer (score 1):

Consider the following.

```
$(function(){
  $.getJSON("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/bimobaskoro/hewan/main/kucing.json", function (data) {
      var html = $("<div>", {
        class: "content"
      });
      $("<h1>").html(data.judul).appendTo(html);
      $("<p>").html(data.isi).appendTo(html);
      $("#content").append(html);
  });
}
```

As GitHub is not apart of the same domain, you may encounter CORS issues. If so, you might consider [JSONP](https://learn.jquery.com/ajax/working-with-jsonp/).

Comment: Github user content supports CORS but definitely does not support JSONP

Comment: @Phil I was unsure, so thanks for the confirmation.

Comment: Just an FYI, you can't simply drop in JSONP. It requires specific handling of the response on the server-side and few support it these days

Comment: Thank you for the answer, I've tried the code but the data doesn't appear, just a white page.